# How do I handle a keyboard press event in ionic/cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, dom-events

I have an ionic application I am developing, and I need a way to handle the return key. When I press the key on the keyboard, the application reloads, like, from the beginning (login). So no matter where I am, and I am using the keyboard, pressing enter has that effect. The problem is irregardless of the platform or device type. How do I best resolve this?

Comment: I suggest you to add more details about what you've tried. Not really possible to help you with so few input.

Answer (score 0):

For return key it is same as javascript

```
if(characterCode == 13)
   {
     return false; // returning false will prevent the event from bubbling          up.
   }
   else
   {
      return true;
    }
```

On htl tag of input aff and call this scope function